# how to import all iCloud contacts into Windows 10 People

Tags: icloud, contacts

how can I import all my iCloud contacts into the Windows 10 People app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your contacts as vCards, then import these into Outlook/your mail client. If you can tell me what type of mail client you use, I can give specific instruction.

[image]

Comment: This will work but, just to clarify for the OP, it will not keep your iCloud and Windows contacts in sync.  This is a 1-time only export/import.

Comment: @fsb Yup. He said import, so I assumed that he wasn't planning on syncing them.

Comment: Agreed, I was just throwing it out there.